# Where to add content and customize page title in woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add content after the page title and customize the style of page where all products are listed in woocommerce, but I have no idea where is the file that I can copy to my custom theme, I have been able to customize the products in the loop but don't know where to customize this?
On inspect element it is the `h1` element with a `class page-title`:

```
<h1 class="page-title">Nettbutikk</h1>
```

Comment: Yes, I have managed to find it already, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php` is the file you are looking for. You can copy `single-product/title.php` to `yourchildthemefolder/woocommerce/single-product/title.php`

Here is a link to their github of that file so you can see it for yourself. Let me know if this helped! :)
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/title.php

Comment: That is not the file I need, I need to change the title of the page where I list all products, not the single product.

Comment: You need to change the title of the shop page? That is not what the original question is asking. Please edit your question to clarify your request.

Comment: Nowhere in my question I have suggested that I need to change the single page or shop page title, but I have edited the question accordingly, I apologize for the confusion. I have found the file where I can customize the title of the product list page, I will post my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear all went well

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To edit the woocommerce product list page, the file `woocommerce/archive-product.php` needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce Listing products page add content after product title using given hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'after_shop_loop_item_title', 1 );
```

Add this code in functions.php of current active theme.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'after_shop_loop_item_title', 1 );
function after_shop_loop_item_title() {
   global $post;
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ); 
  $text = "<p> (";
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $text .= $term->name;
   }
   $text .= ") </p>";
   echo $text;

}
```

Reference by: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/